# DBMS_METADATA and other packages invalid

Tags: oracle, database, utility

I am running a database on my local system, and accessing it through my laptop in home network. Today, I happened to check the status of SYS objects, and found that DBMS_METADATA, and DATA_PUMP packages were invalid among others. I am unable to run EXPDP utilities as well. 
Any ideas on how to recompile this object and correct the status?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: They should recompile automatically, but then they shouldn't have gone invalid anyway. There's a `dbms_utility.compile_schema` that would avoid dependency issues, but that assumes that is valid, and I'm not sure about running it against `SYS`. Does `show errors package body dbms_metadata` reveal anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I finally figured it out - although this is a bit of a brute force method. Inside the admin tools, I had to run catalog.sql and catproc.sql - which re-created the sys objects.

This, followed by utlrp.sql resolved all my problems, and now all objects are succesfully compiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlplus / as sysdba @?/rdbms/admin/utlrp
```

should recompile all invalid objects.
Question that remains is: why/how/when did they become invalid, have they ever been valid?
Did you check dba_registry?

```
select * from dba_registry;
```

Normally all components should be valid.

Comment: Hello, I did check the dba_registry, and running utlrp does not help either. The thing is - while I run utlrp from sys as sysdba, I have around 20 additional schemas for different parts of my project. I can see that multiple objects are in an uncompiled state in those schemas (test objects etc) - but utlrp exits with zero errors. Moreover, count(*) on UTLRP compiled objects returns 0. I have hit a wall here...

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: I should have mentioned this before - my database had crashed last week - accidental deletion of a few folders. I had to restore the folder from a different installation. Export utilities dont work now. However, the uncompiled objects exist only in one sid - that led me to believe that this had nothing to do with the current issue...

Comment: So you have 1 ORACLE_HOME that serves more databases, each with their own ORACLE_SID. One database has problems. What files exactly were located in the removed folders? If you connect to your hurt database using SQLDeveloper, connected as sysdba, what are the compilation errors you get to see there? Does the dba_registry show that all components are valid?

Comment: What files exactly were located in the removed folders - 'bin' among others. Cant login as sysdba now through SQLDeveloper, however, I connected as system - and dba_registry shows DBMS_REGISTRY_SYS.VALIDATE_CATPROC,VALIDATE_OWM,DBMS_REGXDB.VALIDATEXDB and VALIDATE_APEX as invalid. Major issue I guess? Thanks for all the help so far!

Comment: And the database is open for read and write? (select open_mode from v$database;) where are your datafiles? (select name, status from v$datafile;)